# Keeping additional column when normalizing list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing `id` and list of dicts:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'list_of_dicts': [[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 11, 'b': 22}],
                      [{'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'a': 33, 'b': 44}]],
    'id': [100, 200]
})
```

and I want to normalize it like this:

```
    id   a   b
0  100   1   2
0  100   3   4
1  200  11  22
1  200  33  44
```

This gets most of the way:

```
pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict(item)
    for item in df.list_of_dicts
])
```

but is missing the `id` column.

I'm most interested in readability.

Comment: You should really really consider what you are doing to give you `df`. It's a huge red-flag if you have a `pd.DataFrame` that has *other* containers inside of it, especially something like a list of dicts.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Nested json is the source of this. I don't know how to make `normalize_json()` solve this either.

Comment: @Hatshepsut, i agree with  juanpa.arrivillaga. Try to ask a new question and put there your source nested JSON file.

Comment: @OldGeeksGuide have you tried to see what `df` contains? Hint, it's shape is `(2,2)`...

Comment: `pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in zip(df.id, df.list_of_dicts)})`

Comment: `df.set_index('id').list_of_dicts.apply(pd.Series).stack().apply(pd.Series)`

Comment: @MaxU the column is even called `list_of_dicts`

Comment: My bad, comment deleted.

Comment: Those are ugly inefficient answers.  You don't want those.  Follow @MaxU's advice and post the source and maybe we get your end goal in a better way.

Comment: @piRSquared - Agreed, not beautiful.  Changed to a more 'pandamic' style, is that better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
d = {
    'list_of_dicts': [[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 11, 'b': 22}],
                     [{'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'a': 33, 'b': 44}]],
    'id': [100, 200]
}

df = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(x) for ld in d['list_of_dicts'] for x in ld])
id = [[x]*len(l) for l,x in zip(d['list_of_dicts'],d['id'])]
df['id'] = pd.Series([x for l in id for x in l])
```

EDIT - Here's a simpler  version

```
t = [[('id', i)]+list(l.items()) for i in d['id'] for ll in d['list_of_dicts'] for l in ll]

df = pd.DataFrame([dict(x) for x in t])
```

And, if you really want the `id` column first, you can change `dict` to `OrderedDict` from the `collections` module.

Comment: PlusOne from me.  But to be a pain... get that `id` column as the first :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I call an incomprehension

```
pd.DataFrame(
    *list(map(list, zip(
        *[(d, i) for i, l in zip(df.id, df.list_of_dicts) for d in l]
    )))
).rename_axis('id').reset_index()

    id   a   b
0  100   1   2
1  100  11  22
2  200   3   4
3  200  33  44
```